# How do I keep a responsive background image from clipping?

Tags: css, background

I have a responsive background image [here](http://hobblecreek.us/preview/) and it works well in most screen sizes, however, on the iPad/tablet size it clips the edge of the windmill blades.

Here is the CSS I am using for the space:

```
background: url('/image/background-img.jpg') no-repeat; 
width: 100%;  
background-position: 0% 25%;
background-size: cover; 
background-position:center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

How can I continue to fill the background but not clip the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the expected behavior of `background-size:cover`. It displays the image as small as possible, making sure it covers all the element and cutting off (cropping) the excess.

You'll want to adjust the `min-height` of your element until you are happy with the result. To keep it from being cut (too much). To keep it from interfering with how it looks on different screens, you might want to wrap your special rules for tablets in a specific `@media` query. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .jumbotron { 
        min-height: 62vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: The truth is always liberating, even if you had hoped for an 'easier' way. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to play with it, see if any adjustment is needed for `portrait` orientation (`max-height` might work well there). Just resize the browser and tweak your CSS until you're happy. You're welcome.